# Appending values to a struct and printing it

Tags: c, linux, shell

I have just started using structs and I am trying to append the variable names and its contents to the struct variables. For example.

INPUT:

> PATH, getenv("PATH")

OUTPUT:

> Var Name: PATH

> Var Contents: /usr/sbin

This is my struct declaration

```
int var_counter = 0; 

typedef struct ENV_VARIABLES
{
    char var_name[MAX_VAR_NAME]; // Stored the Variable Name ie PATH
    char var_content[MAX_SIZE]; // Stores the Variable Contents ie \home\bin\shell...

}env_variable;

env_variable *env_vars;
```

Here I am passing the parameters to the environVars() then printing them.

```
void iniEnvVars()
{
    environVars("PATH", getenv("PATH"));
    environVars("PROMPT", shellname);
    environVars("CWD", getcwd("CWD", MAX_ARGS));
    environVars("USER", getenv("USER"));
    environVars("SHELL", "/home/.../");
    environVars("TERMINAL", ttyname(STDIN_FILENO));
    environVars("EXITCODE", EXITCODE);

    printVars();
}
```

Here I am adding the contents to the struct.

```
int environVars(char *env_name, char *env_content)
{
    // First we want to check if there are any stored items in the struct
    // If there isnt, we store the first env_name and its contents; 
    // Else, we check if it is there, else we add it to the struct. 
    // If it is already there we modify its contents. 

    if(var_counter == 0)
    {    
        var_counter++;
        env_vars = calloc((size_t)var_counter, sizeof(env_variable));

        strcpy(env_vars[var_counter].var_name, env_name);
        strcpy(env_vars[var_counter].var_content, env_content);
       
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < var_counter; i++)
        {
            if(strcmp(env_name, env_vars[i].var_name) == 0)
            {
                printf("Found\n");
                printf("Modifying Variable Contents\n");
                strcpy(env_vars[i].var_content, env_content);
                break;
            }
            else
            {   
                var_counter++;
                env_vars = realloc(env_vars,(var_counter)*sizeof(env_variable));
                strcpy(env_vars[i].var_name, env_name);
                strcpy(env_vars[i].var_content, env_content);
                break;
                
            }
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Here I am printing them.

```
void printVars()
{
    if(var_counter == 0)
    {
        printf("There are no Enviromental Variables stored.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < var_counter; i++)
        {
            printf("Var Name: %s\n\n ", env_vars[i].var_name);
            printf("Var Contents: %s\n\n ", env_vars[i].var_content);
        }
    }
}
```

I made use of calloc and realloc, but I am not quite sure if I were supposed to use malloc.

The error occuring is that it is not printing anything.
Ive did run a debug and the same thing happened. Nothing was printing.

Comment: Not sure if it's you problem but you need to look through all the existing vars before you decide to add a new one.

Comment: `var_counter ` seems undefined... did you forget to post the definition?

Answer (score 2):

Bug #1:

```
if(var_counter == 0)
{    
    var_counter++;
    env_vars = calloc((size_t)var_counter, sizeof(env_variable));

    strcpy(env_vars[var_counter].var_name, env_name);
    strcpy(env_vars[var_counter].var_content, env_content);
   
}
```

What actually happen when `var_counter` is zero, is this:

```
    var_counter = 1;
    env_vars = calloc(1, sizeof(env_variable));

    strcpy(env_vars[1].var_name, env_name);
    strcpy(env_vars[1].var_content, env_content);
                    ^
                    oh dear
```

You are writing outside the allocated memory

It should be:

```
    strcpy(env_vars[0].var_name, env_name);
    strcpy(env_vars[0].var_content, env_content);
```

Bug #2:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < var_counter; i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(env_name, env_vars[i].var_name) == 0)
        {
            printf("Found\n");
            printf("Modifying Variable Contents\n");
            strcpy(env_vars[i].var_content, env_content);
            break;
        }
        else
        {   
            // YOU DON'T WANT THIS !!
            var_counter++;
            env_vars = realloc(env_vars,(var_counter)*sizeof(env_variable));
            strcpy(env_vars[i].var_name, env_name);
            strcpy(env_vars[i].var_content, env_content);
            break;
            
        }
    }
```

The `else` makes reallocate and overwrite old entries again and again. You don't want that.

The code in the `else` should be **after** the loop. And only be executed in no match was found in the loop.

Comment: So, i should increment after the input or else I can just strcpy(env_vars[var_counter-1].var_name, env_name);

Comment: @AlfredGrech Or subtract one... but notice that the `calloc` needs a non-zero value